# Error in changing the main title of an R plot using psych package

Tags: r, plot, psych

In the help page of the psych package, it says that I can pass more graphic parameters to the `outlier()` function. My syntax is really simple and as follows:

`outlier(na.omit(data[,51:56]), plot = TRUE, main = 'my title')`

This returns: *Error in plot.default(sx, sy, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, ...) : 
  formal argument "main" matched by multiple actual arguments*. I have the feeling this means that the function tries to have the default title (by the psych package) as well as the title I give (i.e. `my title`).

Is there a way to overwrite this or fix it? Or probably I am doing something that needs to be fixed.

**Reproducible example**

```
A <- floor(runif(30, 1,5))
B <- floor(runif(30, 1,5))
C <- floor(runif(30, 1,5))
D <- floor(runif(30, 1,5))
E <- floor(runif(30, 1,5)) 
f <- floor(runif(30, 1,5))

sample.data <- data.frame(A, B, C, D, E, f)

outlier(sample.data, plot = TRUE, main = 'my title')
```

Comment: It's very hard to guess what causes the issue. Please provide [example data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) in order to make your issue reproducible!

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Please see the edited question for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I clear the color of title. Hope to solve your problem.

```
outlier(sample.data, plot = TRUE, col.main = NA)
title("My Title")
```

Comment: You have solved it. Very simple, very effective :) Thanks!